# awk syntax to invoke function with argument read from a file

Tags: unix

I have a function

```
xyz()
{
x=$1*2
echo x
}
```

then I want to use it to replace a particular column in a csv file by `awk`.

File `input.csv`:

```
abc,2,something    
def,3,something1
```

I want output like:

```
abc,4,somthing    
def,6,something1
```

Command used:

```
cat input.csv|awk -F, -v v="'"`xyz "$2""'" 'BEGIN {FS=","; OFS=","} {$2=v1; print $0}'
```

Open file input.csv, calling function xyz by passing file 2nd filed as argument and result is stored back to position 2 of file, but is not working!

If I put constant in place of $2 while calling function it works:

Please help me to do this.

```
cat input.csv|awk -F, -v v="'"`xyz "14""'" 'BEGIN {FS=","; OFS=","} {$2=v1; print $0}'
```

This above line of code is working properly by calling the `xyz` function and putting the result back to 2<sup>nd</sup> column of file `input.csv`, but with only 14*2, as 14 is taken as constant.

Comment: do you know that can create functions in awk, or if you only need to multiply a column value by 2 you can say `awk '{$2*=2;print}' file` ? good luck.

Answer (score 2):

There's a back-quote missing from your command line, and a UUOC (Useless Use of Cat), and a mismatch between variable `v` on the command line and `v1` in the `awk` program:

```
cat input.csv|awk -F, -v v="'"`xyz "$2""'" 'BEGIN {FS=","; OFS=","} {$2=v1; print $0}'
                         ^ Here        ^ Here                            ^ Here
```

That should be written using `$(…)` instead:

```
awk -F, -v v="'$(xyz "$2")'" 'BEGIN {FS=","; OFS=","} {$2=v; print $0}' input.csv
```

This leaves you with a problem, though; the function `xyz` is invoked once by the shell before you start your `awk` script running, and is never invoked by `awk`.  You simply can't do it that way.  However, you can define your function in `awk` (and on the fly):

```
awk -F, 'BEGIN { FS = ","; OFS = "," }
         function xyz(a) { return a * 2 }
         { $2 = xyz($2); print $0 }' \
    input.csv
```

For your two-line input file, it produces your desired output.